# Apply implicit function theorem on $z^3 - 3xyz = 1$ and $z = z(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

To solve this I first rearrange $z^3 - 3xyz - 1 = 0$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ =  $3z^2z'-3xyz'-3yz$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ =  $3zz' -3xyz'-3z$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial z}$ =  $3z^2-3xy$

Now to apply the implicit function theorem do I just need to plug in the values in the formula $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{-F_x}{F_z}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{-F_y}{F_z}$ ?

I would require some directions solving this if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $z'$? We assume that $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, so it has partial derivatives $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.
They can be calculated by the implicit function theorem using the partial derivatives of $F$, which are equal to
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} =  -3yz
$$
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =  -3xz
$$
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} =  3z^2-3xy
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{F_x}{F_z}= -\frac{-3yz}{3z^2-3xy}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -\frac{F_y}{F_z}= -\frac{-3xz}{3z^2-3xy}
$$